# Entity Framework updating two databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

As I've mentioned in a couple other questions, I'm currently trying to replace a home-grown ORM with the Entity Framework, now that our database can support it.

Currently, we have certain objects set up such that they are mapped to a table in our internal database *and* a table in the database that runs our website (which is not even in the same state, let alone on the same server).  So, for example:

```
Part p = new Part(12345);
p.Name = "Renamed part";
p.Update();
```

will update both the internal and the web databases simultaneously to reflect that the part with ID 12345 is now named "Renamed part".  This logic only needs to go one direction (internal -> web) for the time being.  We access the web database through a LINQ-to-SQL DBML and its objects.

I **think** my question has two parts, although it's possible I'm not asking the right question in the first place.

1. Is there any kind of "OnUpdate()" event/method that I can use to trigger validation of "Should this be pushed to the web?" and then do the pushing?  If there isn't anything by default, is there any other way I can insert logic between `.SaveChanges()` and when it hits the database?
2. Is there any way that I can specify for each object which DBML object it maps to, and for each EF auto-generated property which property on the L2S object to map to?  The names often match up, but not always so I can't rely on that.  Alternatively, can I modify the L2S objects in a generic way so that they can populate themselves from the EF object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with.  Note that the implementation of `IAdvantageWebTable` is inherited from the existing base class, so nothing special needed to be done for EF-based classes, once the T4 template was modified to inherit correctly.

```
public partial class EntityContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
    {
        var modified = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added); // Get the list of things to update
        var result = base.SaveChanges(options); // Call the base SaveChanges, which clears that list.
        using (var context = new WebDataContext()) // This is the second database context.
        {
            foreach (var obj in modified)
            {
                var table = obj.Entity as IAdvantageWebTable;
                if (table != null)
                {
                    table.UpdateWeb(context); // This is IAdvantageWebTable.UpdateWeb(), which calls all the existing logic I've had in place for years.
                }
            }
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Sql Server replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: One of the databases is not using Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inter-connect the two together as it seems you're saying with question 2.
Just have the two separate databases with their own EF or L2S models and abstract them away using repositories with domain objects.

Comment: Once it comes to querying from both in one query you can't just "abstract" the two DBs away for performance reasons.

Comment: Any suggestions for generating said domain objects?  One of the specific reasons for trying to switch to EF is to avoid having to manually manage object-to-database mappings for both databases, but if I'm custom building objects, it defeats that point.  That's why I'm looking for a way to specify it on the EF-generated object, so I only need to manage one side of it.